# Java convert date to EST timezone to respecting DST

Tags: java, datetime, timezone

I want to get the current date converted to America/Montreal timezone. I'm doing it like this:

```
Date date = new Date();
TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone ("America/Montreal");
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(timeZone);
cal.setTime(date);
String whatIWant = "" + cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ':'+ 
                   cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE)+ ':'+ cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);

log.info(whatIWant);
```

The conversion is just fine but I was wondering how robust this code is. What will happen when in no daylight saving?

Comment: You say to *ignore* the use of deprecated APIs, but they're clearly relevant here, as that `Date` constructor uses the current time zone. It's entirely unclear what the problem is. Also, why aren't you using SimpleDateFormat?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That code is fine. Java automatically takes winter time or summer time into account.

You could also do this by using a `DateFormat` object to convert the date to a string, setting the desired time zone on the `DateFormat` object:

```
Date date = new Date();

DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

// Tell the DateFormat that you want the time in this timezone
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Montreal"));

String whatIWant = df.format(date);
```

Comment: Thanks, your first two sentences answer my question! Do you have any idea why, when I set the manually the Date, the conversion is done again in EDT and not EST?

Comment: @gpol Because on 28 December, it's winter time (EDT), not summer time (EST).

Comment: Isn't it the other way around? I mean isn't EDT the summer time and EST the winter time?

Comment: @gpol Yes, you're right, see [EDT](http://www.timeanddate.com/library/abbreviations/timezones/na/edt.html) and [EST](http://www.timeanddate.com/library/abbreviations/timezones/na/est.html).